# how to make a loading animation with my code

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to make the boxes rotate. I tried transformation, JS, and even html special code. I do suck at CSS, so this is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
//great code from Scriptkiddy1337 on stack overflow
const pageStack=[];
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  url = url || window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
  var templates = document.getElementsByClassName('sitecontent');
  for (var i = 0, v; v = templates[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, x; x = v.childNodes[j]; j++) {
      if (x.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        pageStack.push(x);
      }
    }  
  }
  var pageIndex = getParameterByName('page') || '0';
  loadPage(pageIndex);
});
function loadPage(index) {
  if (index >= pageStack.length || index < 0) {
    document.body.innerText = '404 Page not found';
    return;
  }
  document.body.innerHTML = '';
  document.body.appendChild(pageStack[index]);
}
</script>
<style>
box{
  transition: 3s;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:fixed;
  transform:/*im confused here*/;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pageholder class="sitecontent">
<page>
<animator>
  <!--I want them to rotate in a circle-->
  <box style="background-color:red">.</box><br><br><br>
  <box style="background-color:red">.</box><br><br><br>
  <box style="background-color:red">.</box><br><br><br>
</animator>
<a href="?page=1">Next Page</a>
</page>
<page>
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<hr>
<p>Need help :(</p>
</page>
</pageholder>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to transform CSSstuff, JS animations (which I also kinda suck at), and even special HTML code. I might be missing something, but as far as I know (which isn't a lot, unfortunately), I have done nearly everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you read up on [CSS Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```
<style>
/* The animation code */
@keyframes rotateBox {
  to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
box{
  transition: 3s;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  /* Use the animation here */
  animation: rotateBox 3s;
}
</style>
```